# IF statement in BASH isn't doing what's expected

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, if-statement

Got a very simple script which checks barcodes basically. There's two barcodes that have to be checked that they are not confused when being made into a variable.

Basically the first barcode should contain only numbers 0-9, and the second barcode should contain two letters, then some numbers, then two more letters, like AB123456789CD.

If they're confused and read in the wrong order then it plays an error sound. This is what I have so far, the top one's working, but I'm not sure it it's the best solution, and the bottom one doesn't do what I want:

```
echo -e $BLUE"Please scan the first barcode"$ENDCOLOUR
read -p "Barcode: " BARCODE1
if [[ "$BARCODE1" =~ [a-z] ]] ; then
play -q ./error.wav
else

echo -e $BLUE"Please scan the second barcode"$ENDCOLOUR
read -p "Barcode: " BARCODE1
if [[ "$BARCODE2" =~ [a-z0-9] ]] ; then
play -q ./error.wav
else

echo "'$BARCODE1',$BARCODE2'" >> barcodes.csv
fi
fi
```

What's wrong? And is there a more optimal means of achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only numbers:

```
if ! [[ $BARCODE1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
```

Because of the `+` sign this is going to enter the if statement for empty strings as well. `+` means one or more times and `*` means zero or more time.

Two characters, numbers, two characters:

```
if ! [[ $BARCODE1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$ ]]; then
```

Once again, this is not going to match for strings like 'AABB'. If you think that 'AABB' is a valid barcode, then use this:

```
if ! [[ $BARCODE1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$ ]]; then
```

EDIT:

Also, if you know exact count of numbers in a barcode, then you could use `{n}`

```
if ! [[ $BARCODE1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$ ]]; then
```

Which means *2 letters, 9 numbers, 2 letters*

Comment: I simply added ! to negate the expressions

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko That's good. You still need to quote your regexps. Maybe I'll just edit your post for you.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: No quotes around regex in BASH. I rolled back your changes.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Within `[[ ... ]]` quoting the rhs would force it to be matched as a string.

Comment: `if ! [[ "$BARCODE1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$ ]]; then` - worked perfect for me! Thanks very very much!